# Home Assistant Sensor API Specification, how to set a unique_id via REST?

Tags: sensors, home-assistant

Years ago I built a temperature sensor that would push (http post) readings to a server / dashboard system I had written. In lieu of expanding requirements, I've decided to switch to Home Assistant as my backend. Though it is possible to send the data to HA, the documentation is spotty. Namely I'm looking for the full JSON for the post body (an OpenAPI spec would be nice) and more details around how sensors function, and things "like can I set a **unique_id** so that they are editable in HA?", etc.

So far I've been working off the little bits of information around the API, some examples, and inferences from other documents for the python api (internal server code).

REST API
https://developers.home-assistant.io/docs/api/rest/
Sensor post info from HTTP integration
https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/http/#sensor
General Sensor Docs
https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/sensor#device-class

Comment: Can you change the code on the temperature sensor to send via MQTT rather than HTTP push? This would be a more 'natural' way to work with HA, where an MQTT sensor would then pick this data up

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you're looking for is `value_json`?

Here's how I'm fetching `value` out of a simple webserver which returns this basic json object `{ key: value }`, although one difference is that I'm polling and using GET.

```
rest:
  - resource: http://192.168.0.122/status
    sensor:
      - name: "Data from my server"
        value_template: "{{ value_json.key }}"
```

Tip: Go to Developer Tools -> Template for a sandbox-like environment where you can rapidly prototype your value_template

Comment: That's an example for pulling, not pushing into HA.